# AWS CLI CloudFront Invalidate All Files

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-cloudfront

I am attempting to invalidate an entire static website. The following command does not seem to invalidate `/index.html` and gives an odd output of items to be invalided, as shown below. Is this AWS CLI behaviour normal or am I missing something? Thanks!

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths /*
```

Output:

```
{
    "Invalidation": {
    "Status": "InProgress", 
    "InvalidationBatch": {
        "Paths": {
            "Items": [
                "/lib32", 
                "/home", 
                "/vmlinuz", 
                "/core", 
                "/proc", 
                "/var", 
                "/dev", 
                "/usr", 
                "/etc", 
                "/initrd.img", 
                "/cdrom", 
                "/lost+found", 
                "/root", 
                "/tmp", 
                "/lib", 
                "/dead.letter", 
                "/lib64", 
                "/boot", 
                "/sys", 
                "/run", 
                "/bin", 
                "/sbin", 
                "/mnt", 
                "/opt", 
                "/snap", 
                "/media", 
                "/copyright", 
                "/srv"
            ], 
            "Quantity": 28
        },
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

That's your shell doing [expansion of local filenames](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).

That's what you're essentially asking for since the `*` isn't quoted.

<strike>Either `--paths '*'` or</strike> Specifying `--paths '/*'`¹ will do what you intend.  Quoting the wildcard keeps it as a literal string rather than what you're seeing.

---

¹The CloudFront console allows you to specify either `*` or `/*` to invalidate the entire distribution; by contrast, the CLI expects `/*`.  This, in turn, is because the underlying API also expects `/*`.  When you use `*` in the console, the leading slash is silently added by the console before the console makes the request to the CloudFront API.

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thank you Michael. To further contribute, on version `aws-cli/1.11.36 Python/2.7.12 Darwin/16.4.0 botocore/1.4.93`, using the `--paths '*'` value gives the error: `An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: Your request contains one or more invalid invalidation paths.` 

You should use `--paths '/*'` instead for a successful response

Comment: @damusix thanks for the tip on the need for the leading `/`.  Updated accordingly.

Comment: this was not entire correct path specification. Atleast on my windows console using this kind of path cause an error. This should be in double quotes (windows atleast)
You must use --paths "/*"

Comment: I was using gitbash with windows and having a problem. I had to add `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` prefix to my command. eg: `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 aws cloudfront create-invalidation ...`

Answer (score 51):

Example of invalidation of cloudfront distribution via aws cli :

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id <DistributionID> --paths "/*"
```

Example :

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id E1B1A4GHK9TTE --paths "/*"
```

To list or get cloudfront  distribution id you can use console or via cli :

```
aws cloudfront list-distributions 
aws cloudfront list-distributions | grep Id
```

Answer (score 12):

Maybe on windows (using cmd) you can use the *path* without quotes, but on bash environment (linux, mac) the character `*` it's a special char.
You need to pass the *path* inside quotes to work cross-platform:

```sh
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths '/*'
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the above answers, you can use this one command:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $(aws cloudfront list-distributions --query 'DistributionList.Items[*].Id | [0]' | tr -d '"') --paths "/*"
```

This basically takes the first CloudFront Distribution in your environment, retrieves the ID, removes the double quotes, and requests the invalidation.

You should see a response similar to:

```
{
"Location": "https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2020-05-31/distribution/E8D4M8HG5JSRS/invalidation/I87QDOK5CWC6O4KWOWBZX75EWN",
"Invalidation": {
    "Id": "I87QDOK5CWC6O4KWOWBZX75EWN",
    "Status": "InProgress",
    "CreateTime": "2023-03-15T00:21:40.285000+00:00",
    "InvalidationBatch": {
        "Paths": {
            "Quantity": 1,
            "Items": [
                "/*"
            ]
        },
        "CallerReference": "cli-1678839700-773660"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is a good answer, but assumes that your account only has one cloudfront distributtion, maybe getting in trouble confusion

Answer (score 0):

In my case, surprisingly, quoting the wildcard didn't work. To solve this, I had to temporarily disable globbing, create the invalidation and then reenable globbing with:

```
set -f
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths "/*"
set +f
```

This shouldn't be your first solution. Use it just in case nothing else works.

Comment: You can use single quotes or escape the asterix with a backslash instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing a script from your *package.json* like the one I followed in [this tutorial](https://itnext.io/deploying-a-web-app-on-aws-using-s3-cloudfront-45f77cd652c6#d65f) remove the path enclosing quotes.
Here's an example usign (and correcting) the one in the tutorial.

```
"scripts": {
  "deploy:live": "npm run build && aws s3 sync dist/ s3://<YOUR_S3_BUCKET_NAME> --delete && npm run-script invalidate-cache:live",
  "invalidate-cache:live": "aws configure set preview.cloudfront true && aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id <CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID> --paths /*"
}
```